# Что это за файл gmon.out ?

Tags: c++

Когда я стал изучать C++, скачал себе `IDE Dev C++` с встроенными компиляторами `gcc` и `g++`.
Писал программы сначала не заметил а потом заметил что когда  пишу любой код например:

```
#include <iostream> 
int main(){
   using namespace std;
   float a = 2.34E+22f;
   float b = a + 1.0f;
   cout << "a = " << a << endl;
   cout << "b - a = " << b - a << endl;
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

да и любой другой и нажимаю ***Скомпилировать и выполнить*** то программа выполняется а когда программа заканчивается и `main` возвращяет `0` то её окно закрывается и ***создаётся файл `gmon.out`***
Не знал у кого спросить у сисадминов или у программистов но когда убедился что создаёт файл не компилятор/IDE ***а сама программа после своего выполнения*** решил спросить у программистов:

1. Почему создаётся этот файл (*gmon.out*) ?
2. Для чего он создаётся ?
3. Что заставляет его создаваться **и как отменить создание программой этого файла** ?

P.S. Заметил что ***файл всегда весит ровно 123КБ и не содержит начало типа `MZђ` как у программ*** а содержит начало типа:

```
Ђ@ `дC й y d   x< дю" к@
```

или

```
Ђ`@ °дC 8й y d   xU дю" 4@
```

а потом биты которые блокнот считает пробелами/табуляцией и если две программы выводят один и тот-же текст то файл у них содержит одно и то же...  Мне кажется что всё что вывел `cout` туда пишется...

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать можете сами обьяснить, ато в google выдача на английском а если написать что такое gmon.out то находит что-то не то...

Comment: gmon.out is the call graph output file of a compile with debugging option -pg, typically.

% man gcc
% man gprof

you can delete it if you have no use for it.



А че непонятного?

Comment: А можно ли отменить создание файла? И создает его не компилятор а сама программа что вообще ставит в тупик...

Comment: @Rules, Вы статью уже прочитали ?

Файл создается **во время выполнения** программы. Создается по требованию (флаги) компилятора. 

Посмотрите с какими флагами IDE вызывает gcc. А лучше делайте все сами, без IDE (это проще и понятней).

Comment: @avp, дело не в английском, а в желании автора самому посмотреть в гугле, что это такое, информация же не скрытая, не запутанная, да и  по ее запросу подходят все первый ссылки в гугле, хоть на русском, хоть на английском, да и гугл транслейтер помог бы ему понять смысл..

Comment: @Gorets, Вы горите желанием научить всех правильно жить ? Или видеть только нравящиеся Вам вопросы ?

Интересно, кому и зачем нужен будет  форум **вопросов**, если на них отвечают - *пойди, поучись*.

Comment: @avp оформите в ответ я приму...

Comment: А кто минуснул то ?

Comment: @Rules, Не я, но с "*автором*" `минуса` согласен...

Попробуйте установить `VB Express`, создать там пустое *консольное приложение* и открыть папку проекта, вот там **реально много дополнительных файлов**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем было спорить, когда сразу можно было чётко ответить на поставленный вопрос.

gmon.out - файл профилирования кода. Проще говор, в нём содержится информация для анализа программы. Этот файл открывается через gprof(GNU profiller).
Если не хотите, что этот файл создавался при каждой компиляции, то нужно указать в настройках Dev cpp: "Project"->"Project options"->"Compiler" вкладка->"Code profiling" и установить "no"

Answer (score 5):

Коротко, gmon.out это файл с данными о том, как программа исполнялась.

Подробнее: [Ускорение кода при помощи GNU-профайлера](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-gnuprof/)

---

@Gorets, неужели из комментария @Rules непонятно, что читать на английском он не может?
Хотя, говорят, что если долго вглядываться в текст на незнакомом языке, то постепенно его смысл начинает доходить до тебя.

Comment: > читать на английском он не может

Незнание законов не освобождает, как бы. Есть же словари и автоматические переводчики. 

Интересная ситуация получается, ОПу любопытно, что это за файл такой, но любопытно не настолько, чтобы посвятить этой теме 2 часа (именно столько прошло между вопросом и ответом) своего драгоценного времени.

Comment: @karmadro4, могу только повторить свой же комментарий

    Вы горите желанием научить всех правильно жить ? Или видеть только нравящиеся Вам вопросы ?

Интересно, кому и зачем нужен будет форум вопросов, если на них отвечают - пойди, поучись.

Comment: Полностью согласен с вами @avp, @karmadro4 считает себя "самым умным" а сам спрашивает "Как извлечь русские слова из строки на JS?" XD

Comment: @avp, вы таким образом сильно опускаете планку. 

> пойди, поучись

В сообществе программистов это подразумевается всегда и везде. Ваше же виденье принимает с распростертыми объятиями тех, кто не желает учиться и вообще делать что-либо самостоятельно. Подобных форумов полно и еще один такой же не очень нужен.

@Rules, посмотритесь в [зеркало](http://www.gamedev.ru/terms/HelpVamp).

Comment: @karmadro4, по поводу вопросов, я считаю так:

**не нравится, пройди мимо**.

Мое отношение к **неправильным** ответам противоположенное. Только я должен быть уверен, что ошибается автор ответа, а не я.

Превращения ХэшКод ни в элитарно-снобистский Хабр, ни в бездарный ВиО не хочу.

Comment: @avp, очень печальные у вас сравнения. Не буду разоряться по поводу иллюзии даровитости Быдлабыдл (второй ваш любимый сайтик вообще не к месту помянут), просто укажу на очевидную цель - догнать и перегнать [Америку](http://stackoverflow.COM/). Цитирую:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful 

В частности, нежелание ОПа прочитать документацию по gprof не является оправданием просьб *изложить своими словами* (даже если кому-то нечего делать и он изложит в ответе). *Полезным* поворотом был бы вопрос о том, *что такое профайлер* или *как его отключить*.

Comment: Кстати в 2015 я выучил английский) Жаль чё-то Хешкод забросил аж ... получается на 4 года) Ну с возвращением меня...